# Angular 2+, how to dynamically bind and unbind to mousemove event

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent

I know how to bind to events using the HostListener decorator like this:

```
  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMousemove(event) {
    //Some code on mouse movement.
  }
```

But I would like to be able to bind and unbind to the mousemove event intermittently throughout the lifecycle of a component. I don't know what this type of binding is called, and I can't find anything about it. Should I try to use native JavaScript event binding?

Comment: Can you further explain the context of the problem?

Comment: You can only unbind yourself if you register imperatively. If you use the declarative approach, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div (mouseover)="someOverFunction()" 
     (mouseleave)="someLeaveFunction()">
         <span *ngIf="mouseOverDiv == true">hello mouseover</span>
         <span *ngIf="mouseOverDiv == false">hello mouseleave</span>
</div>
```

TS:

```
mouseOverDiv : boolean = false;

someOverFunction(){
 this.mouseOverDiv = true;  
}

someLeaveFunction(){
 this.mouseOverDiv = false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a output variable like below.

```
 @Output() mouseEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

Use this variable when you want to emit the event like below.

```
 this.mouseEvent.emit({value:paramValue});
```

Call that mouse event where you want to add in html element

```
 <HTMLElement (mouseEvent) = "methodName()"></HTMLElement>
```